# Glide pre loaded image

Tags: android

i am using glide to load locally image. On first activity i loaded five large size images and same images loaded again on second activity but issue is that i already downloaded images on first activity and is available in cache but taking time on second activity when load. 
my first activity code

```
   Glide
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(path)
                .asBitmap()
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                .override(180, 180);
```

and second activity

```
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(path)
            .asBitmap()
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
            .priority(Priority.HIGH)
            .override(180, 180).into(viewHolder.img_android);
```

note that all images size greater than 5 mb.
when i open second activity first time, image take time to load then when again open its loaded so fast. so i want to preload all images on first activity. how is it possible.
my first actvitiy code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_1);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_2);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_3);
    list.add(R.drawable.image_5);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_4);
    list.add(R.drawable.image_6);
    loadImages(list);

    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}


public void loadImages(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Glide
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.get(i))
                .asBitmap()
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                .override(133, 133);

    }
}
```

second activity code:

```
 private void initViews() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<Integer> androidVersions = prepareData();
    DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public ArrayList<Integer> prepareData() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_1);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_2);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_3);
    list.add(R.drawable.image_5);
    list.add(R.drawable.iamge_4);
    list.add(R.drawable.image_6);
    return list;
}
```

and adapter:

```
 @Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
      .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(android.get(i))
            .asBitmap()
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .priority(Priority.HIGH)
            .override(133, 133).into(viewHolder.img_android);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tv_android;
    private ImageView img_android;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        img_android = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
    }
}
```

Comment: try using getApplicationContext in your second activity while initializing Glide object.

Comment: @nnn i guess it will not work

Comment: try using: `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)`

Comment: i try this diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) but not working its loaded when open first time second activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 .placeholder(R.drawable.your_image) // for default image.
```

For your requirement read **[Using Cache Strategies](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)**

- **DiskCacheStrategy.NONE** caches nothing, as discussed
- **DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE** caches only the original full-resolution image. In our example above that would be the 1000x1000 pixel one
- **DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT** caches only the final image, after reducing  the resolution (and possibly transformations) (default
  behavior)
- **DiskCacheStrategy.ALL** caches all versions of the image

Comment: no i dont want to use that because on first activity i already loaded all images but i dont want to show on first activity. when i reached on second activity want  loaded all images from cache without any loaded time

Comment: what about `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)`

Comment: and issue arise that when i reached on second activity first time its take time to load but when again open its show without any time delay so not understand that  why taking time when open second activity first time as  i already loaded on first activity before

Comment: comment `diskCacheStrategy` Clean -rebuild and run  .see result

Comment: read https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics and https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/281

Comment: try with `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL`

Comment: i try this DiskCacheStrategy.ALL but loaded when open first time second activity

Comment: i updated my post please check also add activity code.

Comment: okay . for test case add 2  images instead 6. Because of, you have heavy size images

Comment: i observed that when open second activity first time its take some seconds to load then when backpressed and again open second activity its take 0 second to load i also tried with 2 images on both acitivity

Comment: reduce value of `.override(, )`

Comment: i dont want to reduce size as well. i want to preload all images on first activity broo

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi any solutions yet ?